# Anyone else having problems joining domain in OS X 10.10.2?

Tags: macos, network, windows

I am (have confirmed I have rights since I can remove and join a Windows 7 box) having problems joining a Yosemite OS X 10.10.2 to the domain--I receive a "authentication server encountered an error while attempting the requested operation (5202)" no matter if I use the GUI to join the "Network Account Server" or use DSCONFIGAD command-line command at Terminal.

I was able to join two Mac Minis on 10.10.x a few months ago but I am having problems with a new-out-of-the-box Mini right now. Even tried erasing and reinstalling from a OS X 10.10.2 thumb drive.

Comment: Seeing that time differences are a problem, I made sure that the NTP server was matching the one used on the domain and there was no variance in time.

Comment: Must have been some other network change internally as rolling back (reinstalling) to OS X 10.10.0 didn't change the inability to join the domain. Error 5202 still.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, this was purely my own fault. After turning on Directory Services logging and discovering that no attempt was made it turned out to be the Ethernet jack the Mac was plugged into was going into another non-production lab environment. 5502 isn't super helpful by itself!

Answer (score 1):

Our issue turned out to be that the time on the computer was different from our domain controller. Once we set the time correctly we were able to join without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

We had this error:

> dsconfigad: Authentication server encountered an error while attempting the requested operation. (5202)

and in the `/var/log/opendirectoryd.log`

```
2016-03-10 11:08:30.210484 GMT - AID: 0x0000000000000000 - 1280.6968, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5.dylib - krb5_get_init_creds: KRB-ERROR -1765328378/Client (XXXX@YYYY.COM) unknown
2016-03-10 11:08:30.210505 GMT - AID: 0x0000000000000000 - 1280.6968, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - password verify for XXXX@YYYY.COM failed with error -1765328378 - 'Client (XXXX@YYYY.COM) unknown'
2016-03-10 11:08:30.210574 GMT - AID: 0x0000000000000000 - 1280.6968, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - ODNodeCustomCall failed with error 'Credential server error' (5202)
...
```

joining a machine running 10.11.x that had been unbound from the domain.  Nothing would allow it to bind - using either OpenDirectory or `dsconfigad`

The fix was deleting the following:

```
/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/config/
/etc/krb5.keytab
/Library/Preferences/OpenDirectory
```

This issue affected two machines which have now been able to successfully bind.

Comment: Note to have a backup since /var/db/dslocal/Nodes/Default/config was a very, VERY bad option for me...that is the default local user database, and removing it required an inordinate amount of permissions changes and sudo rm -rf (which I suppose should have been a sign). We ultimately had to recover the Mac from single-user mode by restoring the backup of the local user database that is taken daily using "xar".
So I wouldn't suggest killing that file, the others though may help. After removing those and restoring the users database, we were finally able to join the Mac to the domain again.